# How to store persistent User Connection Strings with .NET WPF Click-Once

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, clickonce

We're developing a Click-Once WPF Windows Application that retrieves all its data from a database. I implemented a Form where a User could enter the corresponding data and using a SqlConnectionStringBuilder we build the Connection String and that works just fine.

We then add the Connection String to the ConfigurationManager using

```
ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(ConfigurationUserLevel.None);
```

If we use some other ConfigurationUserLevel, the application crashes (I don't know why yet, but I believe the Entity Framework Model tries to load the connection string and doesn't find it, because the file is not stored in the correct User Level?). Now, we store the connection string in a separate file and load it in App.config so we don't have to check it into Version Control:

```
<connectionStrings configSource="connections.config"/>
```

We don't deploy this file because it contains our own development connection strings. Rather, we create an empty file for deployment where the user-entered connection string will be stored. This works completely fine.

Our problem is that with a click-once update, the file will be "lost". What is the best way to store persistent per-user connection strings encrypted in a configuration file? Or should we completely switch to Registry? Or create our own encrypted File somewhere outside the `%APPDATA%/Local/Apps/2.0/...../` folders and load it manually when initializing the Entity Framework Context?

Comment: If the application crashes, add proper logging. Don't assume. There's no problem with using a separate config file, provided you store it in the proper folder. All these things are very well documented.

Comment: If you care about credentials, just *don't* use them. Use Windows Authentication instead. The OS and the application already knows who the user is. No need to ask or store a username

Comment: Hi Panagiotis, thanks for your advice. We are currently working on Logging.

Comment: The thing is, we don't use Windows authentication because the Windows Accounts do not necessarily correspond to the databse accounts.

Comment: Then fix this problem. What's the point of having *different* accounts? Unless you want to allow multiple users to use the same Windows Account to login on the desktop but reenter different database credentials - which doesn't make much sense in 2017 when user switching takes seconds

Comment: If you want to use different permissions per user, define *roles* in the database and add users to them. Better yet, give the roles to Windows groups, and add/remove users to groups. This will allow administrators to change user privileges without having to touch the database.

Comment: We don't have any decision power as to how the database is structured. It's not our decision. We're just making the software and that's how we've been told it should be done. It should be a connection string that is built by using user input. For some things, the admins should be able to do some preconfiguring of the Software and then the user can import a configuration. But that's basically just making a config file and importing it.

Comment: Use windows authentication account with sql server is not secure, since the end user could install any open source database explorer to access whole database easily with his/her windows account directly. The purpose of security will be broken.

Answer (score 1):

You can go to MSDN site it might help you

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997001.aspx 
with the help of below code, you need to modify this code for your requirement, hope this will help.

To create a custom ClickOnce application installer

In your ClickOnce application, add references to System.Deployment and System.Windows.Forms.

Add a new class to your application and specify any name. This walkthrough uses the name MyInstaller.

Add the following Imports or using statements to the top of your new class.

```
using System.Deployment.Application;  
using System.Windows.Forms;
```

Add the following methods to your class.

These methods call InPlaceHostingManager methods to download the deployment manifest, assert appropriate permissions, ask the user for permission to install, and then download and install the application into the ClickOnce cache. A custom installer can specify that a ClickOnce application is pre-trusted, or can defer the trust decision to the AssertApplicationRequirements method call. This code pre-trusts the application
Note:- Permissions assigned by pre-trusting cannot exceed the permissions of the custom installer code.

```
InPlaceHostingManager iphm = null;

    public void InstallApplication(string deployManifestUriStr)
    {
        try
        {
            Uri deploymentUri = new Uri(deployManifestUriStr);
            iphm = new InPlaceHostingManager(deploymentUri, false);
        }
        catch (UriFormatException uriEx)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Cannot install the application: " + 
                "The deployment manifest URL supplied is not a valid URL. " +
                "Error: " + uriEx.Message);
            return;
        }
        catch (PlatformNotSupportedException platformEx)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Cannot install the application: " + 
                "This program requires Windows XP or higher. " +
                "Error: " + platformEx.Message);
            return;
        }
        catch (ArgumentException argumentEx)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Cannot install the application: " + 
                "The deployment manifest URL supplied is not a valid URL. " +
                "Error: " + argumentEx.Message);
            return;
        }

        iphm.GetManifestCompleted += new EventHandler<GetManifestCompletedEventArgs>(iphm_GetManifestCompleted);
        iphm.GetManifestAsync();
    }

    void iphm_GetManifestCompleted(object sender, GetManifestCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        // Check for an error.
        if (e.Error != null)
        {
            // Cancel download and install.
            MessageBox.Show("Could not download manifest. Error: " + e.Error.Message);
            return;
        }

        // bool isFullTrust = CheckForFullTrust(e.ApplicationManifest);

        // Verify this application can be installed.
        try
        {
            // the true parameter allows InPlaceHostingManager
            // to grant the permissions requested in the applicaiton manifest.
            iphm.AssertApplicationRequirements(true) ; 
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("An error occurred while verifying the application. " +
                "Error: " + ex.Message);
            return;
        }

        // Use the information from GetManifestCompleted() to confirm 
        // that the user wants to proceed.
        string appInfo = "Application Name: " + e.ProductName;
        appInfo += "\nVersion: " + e.Version;
        appInfo += "\nSupport/Help Requests: " + (e.SupportUri != null ?
            e.SupportUri.ToString() : "N/A");
        appInfo += "\n\nConfirmed that this application can run with its requested permissions.";
        // if (isFullTrust)
        // appInfo += "\n\nThis application requires full trust in order to run.";
        appInfo += "\n\nProceed with installation?";

        DialogResult dr = MessageBox.Show(appInfo, "Confirm Application Install",
            MessageBoxButtons.OKCancel, MessageBoxIcon.Question);
        if (dr != System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
        {
            return;
        }

        // Download the deployment manifest. 
        iphm.DownloadProgressChanged += new EventHandler<DownloadProgressChangedEventArgs>(iphm_DownloadProgressChanged);
        iphm.DownloadApplicationCompleted += new EventHandler<DownloadApplicationCompletedEventArgs>(iphm_DownloadApplicationCompleted);

        try
        {
            // Usually this shouldn't throw an exception unless AssertApplicationRequirements() failed, 
            // or you did not call that method before calling this one.
            iphm.DownloadApplicationAsync();
        }
        catch (Exception downloadEx)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Cannot initiate download of application. Error: " +
                downloadEx.Message);
            return;
        }
    }

    /*
    private bool CheckForFullTrust(XmlReader appManifest)
    {
        if (appManifest == null)
        {
            throw (new ArgumentNullException("appManifest cannot be null."));
        }

        XAttribute xaUnrestricted =
            XDocument.Load(appManifest)
                .Element("{urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1}assembly")
                .Element("{urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v2}trustInfo")
                .Element("{urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v2}security")
                .Element("{urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v2}applicationRequestMinimum")
                .Element("{urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v2}PermissionSet")
                .Attribute("Unrestricted"); // Attributes never have a namespace

        if (xaUnrestricted != null)
            if (xaUnrestricted.Value == "true")
                return true;

        return false;
    }
    */

    void iphm_DownloadApplicationCompleted(object sender, DownloadApplicationCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        // Check for an error.
        if (e.Error != null)
        {
            // Cancel download and install.
            MessageBox.Show("Could not download and install application. Error: " + e.Error.Message);
            return;
        }

        // Inform the user that their application is ready for use. 
        MessageBox.Show("Application installed! You may now run it from the Start menu.");
    }

    void iphm_DownloadProgressChanged(object sender, DownloadProgressChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        // you can show percentage of task completed using e.ProgressPercentage
    }
```

To attempt installation from your code, call the InstallApplication method. For example, if you named your class MyInstaller, you might call InstallApplication in the following way.

```
MyInstaller installer = new MyInstaller();  
installer.InstallApplication(@"\\myServer\myShare\myApp.application");  
MessageBox.Show("Installer object created.");
```

Comment: Thanks, that looks extremely helpful. I'll have a look into that!